# Migrating shell scripts from Solaris 10 to RHEL 7.5

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, posix

## Source environment:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS machine1 5.10 Generic_150400-63 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise
$ pwd
/
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          13 Nov  1 19:39 /bin/sh -> ../../sbin/sh
```

## Target environment:

```
$ pwd
/root
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Jul 16 12:10 /bin/sh -> bash
$ cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

In target environment, we use shebang line `#!/bin/sh` in every script

---

Shell scripts in solaris environment are using shebang line `#!/usr/bin/ksh` and `#!/bin/sh`

Goal is to migrate shell scripts from Solaris 10 to RHEL 7.5

---

1) Are scripts written solaris korn shell & `/bin/sh` shell, [posix compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/nfindex.html)? for seamless migration to bash(in Linux) without verification of code..

2) If no, What are the verifications required before migrating scripts to Linux?

Comment: very basic script might run smoothly, however command like `devfsadm` or `luxadm` have no equivalent in redhat.

Answer (score 4):

You may *not*  migrate the code without looking at it.  You need to test run the scripts in a safe environment and compare the results with the expected result for the same test on Solaris.  You should also investigate if the fail conditions are the same on both system (missing files, invalid data, etc.).

It doesn't matter how POSIX the *shells* are that the scripts have been written for, as the scripts may well call non-POSIX or Solaris-specific utilities or use non-POSIX shell extensions.  They may also make assumptions about the environment (where files are located, what devices and interfaces are called etc.) that needs to be updated for Linux.

The `ksh` shell on Solaris is *quite different* from `bash` on Linux, so you simply can't expect the `ksh` scripts to "just run" in `sh` or `bash` on Linux.

Comment: Would shellcheck.net give a good start?

Comment: Checking line by line is not a wise idea...

Comment: @overexchange ShellCheck will only ever tell you whether the syntax of the script is ok. It is unable to tell you whether the script does what you think it does or whether it would run ok on Linux.

Comment: @overexchange If I was given a random `ksh` script from a Solaris machine and was told I had to make it run on Linux under `/bin/sh`, I would _definitely_ go through it line by line until I understood it and could see that it would be doing the right thing on Linux too.

Comment: We also have scripts using /bin/sh in Solaris.... as mentioned in query. Do I need to approach similar way like ksh scripts?

Comment: @overexchange As I mentioned in the answer above, the scripts may be run under a POSIX shell on Solaris, but that does not make the _script_ automatically portable if it uses Solaris-specific utilities, or relies on paths etc. that are simply not available on Linux or that may mean something different on Linux.  A script may run on Solaris `/bin/sh` and access `/proc`, but since `/proc` on Solaris is _totally different_ from `/proc` on Linux, the script would not be portable.